# Workday Count-Down Formula when cell has a value entered

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to add a Workday Count Down to my project plan. As soon as the action has been completed (3 installs are done for the day) and I enter 3 in B14 I need my Total Work Days left (N1) to subtract 1 day to show the amount of the work days left to complete the project.

My problem is, it subtracts the amount of installs instead of just 1 day.

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how is it that you're doing it, but you could do an `COUNTA(range)`, that counts cells that are not blank, and subtract it from the number of work days you have.

So it would be like: `NumberOfWorkdays - COUNTA(range)`.